# How to update data in Morris.Bar chart

Tags: javascript, morris.js

This is question is about [morris.bar](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html) implementation in a cshtml page in a .net6 application.

I have a morris.bar chart that gets loaded with two data sets when the page loads. The chart data can be toggled with a dropdown (#drpVolOverviewType).

I have added a second dropdown (#drpTeamOrInd). When this new dropdown is toggled I want the two data sets in the chart to be updated from the DB - per logic that is defined in the controller. The data part works fine. My problem is that the morris.bar does not get updated.

This is the version of my morris.bar:
js/MorrisPlugin/raphael-2.1.0.js

I tried to have it refresh with method this but it didnt work:

```
$('#drpTeamOrInd').change(function () {
    // Call the function with synchronous AJAX and update the MorrisBar chart
    morBarF.setData(getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()));
    morBarC.setData(getCVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()));
});
```

getFVolumeOverviewData and getCVolumeOverviewData are the functions that get the data when the page load and they work fine.

This is the relevant code:

```
  var morBarF;
   var morBarC;

   // Function to initialize MorrisBar charts
   function initializeCharts() {
       // All volume overview
       morBarF = new Morris.Bar({
           // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
           element: 'divChartVolumeOverviewAll',
           data: getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()), // Initial data
           xkey: 'x',
           ykeys: ['y'],
           labels: ['DV']
       });

       // Part volume overview
       morBarC = new Morris.Bar({
           // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
           element: 'divChartVolumeOverviewPart',
           data: getCVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()), // Initial data
           xkey: 'x',
           ykeys: ['y'],
           labels: ['DV']
       });
       $('#divChartVolumeOverviewPart').hide();
       $('#drpVolOverviewType').trigger('change');
   }

   // Call the function to initialize charts
   initializeCharts();

     //Volume overview instrument type dropdown change event
     $('#drpVolOverviewType').change(function () {
            if ($('#drpVolOverviewType').val() == 1) {
                $('#spnMonthToDate').text(fTotalTrade);
                $('#divChartVolumeOverviewF').show();
                $('#divChartVolumeOverviewC').hide();
            } else if ($('#drpVolOverviewType').val() == 2) {
                $('#spnMonthToDate').text(cTotalTrade);
                $('#divChartVolumeOverviewC').show();
                $('#divChartVolumeOverviewF').hide();
            }
        });

   $('#drpTeamOrInd').change(function () {
       // Call the function with synchronous AJAX and update the MorrisBar chart
       morBarF.setData(getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()));
       morBarC.setData(getCVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()));
    });
```

Appreciate your help with this.
Thanks

Comment: A few debugging questions. 1) Are you sure the `change()` event handler is triggered? Does adding `console.log("change")` inside the handler indeed log "change"? 2) If the above is successful. I would double check the response data in the change handler. Store both data responses in 2 variables, log them and pass them forward to `setData()`. Do you see the data being logged?

Comment: @3limin4t0r hi, yes I am sure. If I write it like this:
  $('#drpTeamOrInd').change(function () {
       getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val());
       getCVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val());
    });
Then I can see in debug mode that the controller gets executed and the correct data is returned.

When Its inside the setData() as in the code in the ticket, then it no longer works. I'll try what you suggested though.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I tried 
            fVol= getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val());
            cVol= getCVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val());

            morBarF.setData(cVol);
            morBarF.setData(fVol);

and... that worked. 
So apparently the returned array needs to be assigned to a variable before being passed to morris.bar. Thank you. 

If you answer I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again

Comment: Very strange. In theory that shouldn't fix anything. But hey, glad the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion from 3limin4t0r in the discussion, the solution was to first assign the value to returned by getFVolumeOverviewData($('#drpTeamOrInd').val()) to a variable and then pass it to morris.bar.

I was not aware that in JS it was not possible to execute a function within as a parameter within another method.